# How to increment page number by one

Tags: page-numbering

I am trying to increment a page number by one. (because I'll add something later between those pages) I think it should be pretty simple to do, but everything I tried so far hasn't worked, and I can't find anything of value online.

I think it should look something like this:

```
  \setcounter{page}{\value{page} + 1}
```

But the page number just stays the same, even if I incremented it with 5 or 10...

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: `\stepcounter{page}`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!! You are an hero. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: I'm reluctant to disagree some of those who voted to put on hold but I don't see that it is off-topic and the asker did provide some (non-working) code. How to manually incrementing a counter seems a perfectly reasonable question. Further, I see no reason for a question to be put on hold because it was answered in a comment. [GOM]

Comment: @PeterWilson Answered in comments and putting it on hold as off-topic is wrong. But i am pretty sure that this question was already asked in the almost ten years of TeX.SX and would have been marked as duplicate.